# Attribute Error when trying to setlabel in wx python

Tags: python, live, wxwidgets

This seems like a simple issue but I'm having a very difficult time understanding why I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....py", line 46, in update
    self.Grob3Text.SetLabel('Grob 3:  ' + str(Grob3))
AttributeError: 'Frame' object has no attribute 'Grob3Text'
```

When running the following script:

Please see -

[image].

I understand the message is telling me that the static text variable 'Grob3Text' is not defined in the Frame, but it appears to me that the definition for update event is under the same class.  All I'm trying to do is execute the faultreport function and update the static text.  I have got this working in another script but for whatever reason I am overlooking something here.

Comment: See [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186) for help with code formatting. Please do include textual code though.

Answer (score 0):

You create a local variable `Grob3Text` in `__init__`, but you don't actually store it as an instance attribute on the class instance.  To do that, you could simply do:

```
self.Grob3Text = Grob3Text
```

in `__init__` after you create `Grob3Text`.